# PHP - How to find a specific number in a string?

Tags: php, pattern-matching

I run a sneakers affiliate site and I am trying to match imported product names with existing sneaker models by a keyword. With the many formats around I have to use a number sometimes, and numbers don't get matched with the code I use. I tried all the different php str- functions but none of them seem to like both numbers and strings.

```
 $models = array(
    '106' => 'Vans 106 Vulcanized',
    'alomar' => 'Vans Alomar',
    'atwood' => 'Vans Atwood',
    'authentic' => 'Vans Authentic',
    // List goes on...
 );

 foreach ( $models as $model_keyword => $model_name ) {

     if ( stristr( $product_name, $model_keyword ) !== false ) {

         return $model_name;

     }

 }
```

As you can see I am checking the product name for each of the keywords and when it's found return the model name. Works for every string that contains letters or letters and numbers but not just numbers like the first item in my array.

Any ideas on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `strpos` instead.

```
<?php

$models = array(
    '106' => 'Vans 106 Vulcanized',
    'alomar' => 'Vans Alomar',
    'atwood' => 'Vans Atwood',
    'authentic' => 'Vans Authentic'
    // List goes on...
);

foreach ($models as $key => $name) {
    if (strpos($name, (string)$key) !== false)
        return $name;
}
```

Comment: Or `stripos` for being  not casesensitive.

Comment: Also the same problem. From the docs: **If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.** The product names containing '106' are still ignored.

Comment: @Tim Yes you are right: Cast the `$key`to a string before `(string)$key`. I edited the answer.

Comment: Should've thought of that. This is the solution, thanks

Comment: @Tim But better use `stripos` it's faster ;)

Comment: Is `!== false` necessary?

Comment: @royhowie yes. if the string you are looking for is at position 0 (zero) the if clause would interpret this as false.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php Seems odd that `strpos` returns false instead of -1 for "not found."

Comment: @royhowie Strict typing is not the strength of PHP ;)